# jQuery Javascript add variable to name

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, while-loop

Have the following code:

```
var i = 1;
while (i<22){ 
  $('[id^="trloc"]').show();
  i++;
}
```

I need to add the `value` of `i` to the `id` - something like this:

```
$('[id^="trloc" + i]').show();
```

But I cannot seem to get it to work - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id^="trloc'+ i  +'"').show();
```

simply

```
$('#trloc' + i).show();
```

if you don't have any other part after `i` like: `trloc1_a`,`troloc2_b` etc then second solution will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you - damned apostrophes and semi colons!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('#trloc' + i).show();
```

If you search by id, use '#'. It is both easier and faster.

Comment: Thanks Sanja, appreaciated.